# How to set starting page in Netbeans Java Web project template?

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run a java web project it always opens in my browser the "index.html" page, so I want to choose another page when the project starts.

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the URL to be used when you run your project as follows:

- Select your project in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **Properties...** from the context menu.
- Select **Run** from the list of categories.
- You should see that **Context Path** already is set to something. It is set to `/WebApplication1` in the sample screen shot below. Leave that field alone.
- Specify the **Relative URL** you want to be used when NetBeans runs your application. By default it will be empty. The value you provide will be appended to the context path to construct the URL. In the screen shot below the relative URL is set to `/Servlet1`, so this will be be appended to the context path of `/WebApplication1` to build the URL `http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/Servlet1` to be used when the application is run.
- When your web application is run, the URL to be used is logged to the run window. Note the text `Browsing: http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/Servlet1` near the bottom of the screen shot.

[image: RelativeURL]